# Can't load Wayland session although I selected it from the cog wheel

Tags: nvidia, gnome, wayland

Ubuntu 22.04 and nvidia 525.147.05 with 2080ti.

I want to enter a gnome wayland session, I therefore selected the gnome wayland option from the cogwheel but after I entered my password I just get a blinking cursor and I have to hard reset.

I added the `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` kernel parameter although from what I understand this is just for making the cog wheel appear? (Interestingly before I set the kernel parameter I also got the blinking cursor but after a few seconds it went back into the display manager). Any help is appreciated thanks a lot.

Comment: Check /var/crash for .crash files, which will tell you exactly what crashed and why. Many, many possibilities. Also check your syslog and journal; those are often full of great troubleshooting clues.